# is componentWillReceiveProps suitable for some instant logic?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm making a simple login process by react-redux:

there are two redux-connected components called  `App`
and `Login`,  and a redux state `loggedIn` which will be modified to true after an async call.

I hope to check the `loggedIn` changing in `Login::componentWillReceiveProps`(by compareing with last value),  then call the router's jump method.

but the problem is the `App` also connects to the `loggedIn` state, for displaying some welcome info in header.

so when the `loggedIn` state change, the `App` will first know and re-render,  causing the `Login` child component re-construct and its `componentWillReceiveProps` won't be called, thus the jump could not be executed.

is it something wrong in my solution?? if considering outside this problem , how could we ensure the child's `componentWillReceiveProps` running when its parent re-render? is this method suitable for placeing  important logic??

Comment: if the goal is to navigate elsewhere rather than displaying the Login component it sounds like that logic probably belongs in the App rather than the Login component.  but yes componentWillReceiveProps is the place to detect if props have changed since mounting and do conditional logic.